# How to make key presses on dial pad, programmatically?

Tags: android, keypress, phone-call

I have to write a program to call, using call card. My questions are:
 1. How to know phone is ringing and received at the receiver's end.(e.g. At service provider like 1800).
 2. After received I want to make key presses for desired number on dial pad in program.
 (or if any way to make key press events and append call to first one(e.g.1800), please tell!).

if any idea to append call to SP's number, please Help!

Answer (score 2):

to make call programmatically:

```
Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        call.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        call.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
        startActivity(call);
```

add this permission to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: Thanks vineet for your response. It is easy to know ringing and received of our phone, but how to know the state of our call, that is ringing, received or in other state at receiver's end.
What will be done to know that?

Comment: case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK: gives at least one call exists that is dialing, active, or on hold, and no calls are ringing or waiting......

Answer (score 0):

> After received I want to make key presses for desired number on dial pad in program. (or if any way to make key press events and append call to first one(e.g.1800), please tell!).

This is not possible, sorry.